# Destructuring Different Conditional Return Types

Tags: ecmascript-6, destructuring

I have a function that will return either a string, if there is an error, or two objects, when there is no error. My function looks like this:

```
function logResults(json) {
  const one = json[0]
  const two = json[1]
  const error = json[0].error

  if (error) {
    return 'error at logResults' // string type
  }

  return (one, two) // object type
}
```

My question is would it possible to destructure this function's return types? This line works if two objects are successfully returned: `let [ one, two ] = logResults(json)`, but it won't work if a string is returned. If destructuring is not possible, what is the most efficient way to handle the different return types?

Comment: You can't return 'two objects'. There's a single return value. What exactly is `return (one, two)` supposed to do?

Comment: json[0] and json[1] are nested objects in the object json. return (one, two) will return json[0] and json[1].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> return either a string, if there is an error, or two objects, when there is no error

Uh, don't do that. For exactly the reasons you have demonstrated: the function becomes unusable. Just throw an error or return an array with the two objects.

```
function logResults(json) {
  const [one, two] = json;
  if (one.error) {
    throw new Error('error at logResults');
  }

  return [one, two]; // or just `json`?
}
```

Now you can use destructuring after the call as you imagined.

Comment: This works, but I would like to render a string on the DOM if an error is caught. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Uh, yes, just catch that error: `try { let [ one, two ] = logResults(json); renderNormal(one); renderNormal(two); } catch(err) { renderError(err.message); }`